# Okular not showing installed printers

Tags: printing, pdf, okular

I have installed all Ubuntu Service Pack/Patches

```
Untuntu: 20.04.4 LTS
         64-Bit
         GNOME Version: 3.36.8

Okular: 20.12.3
```

I am only presented with one option for printer (File; Print)
Print to File (PDF)
{drop down arrow does nothing when attempting to see installed printers}

Using LibreOffice or even Doument Viewer gives me my printer options.

**Reason for Okular is I want to use "EVEN" or "ODD" printing by clicking a button vs manually entering the list (ie 2,4,6,8,10,...)*

```
gen6@i5Desktop:~$ lpstat -a
HP-LaserJet-3050 accepting requests since Thu 07 Apr 2022 04:57:36 PM CDT
HP-LaserJet-3050-Fax accepting requests since Fri 24 Dec 2021 03:58:12 PM CST
gen6@i5Desktop:~$ lpstat -l -e
HP-LaserJet-3050 permanent ipp://localhost/printers/HP-LaserJet-3050 hp:/usb/HP_LaserJet_3050?serial=00CNRK166643
HP-LaserJet-3050-Fax permanent ipp://localhost/printers/HP-LaserJet-3050-Fax hpfax:/usb/HP_LaserJet_3050?serial=00CNRK166643
gen6@i5Desktop:~$ lpstat -t
scheduler is running
system default destination: HP-LaserJet-3050
device for HP-LaserJet-3050: hp:/usb/HP_LaserJet_3050?serial=00CNRK166643
device for HP-LaserJet-3050-Fax: hpfax:/usb/HP_LaserJet_3050?serial=00CNRK166643
HP-LaserJet-3050 accepting requests since Thu 07 Apr 2022 04:57:36 PM CDT
HP-LaserJet-3050-Fax accepting requests since Fri 24 Dec 2021 03:58:12 PM CST
printer HP-LaserJet-3050 is idle.  enabled since Thu 07 Apr 2022 04:57:36 PM CDT
printer HP-LaserJet-3050-Fax is idle.  enabled since Fri 24 Dec 2021 03:58:12 PM CST
```

Comment: Give `lpstat -a` and `lpstat -l -e`.

Comment: And `lpstat -t`.

Comment: I did these in order (after I rebooted from initial posting) with no change... =\

Comment: I cannot see the outputs of the requested commands added to the first post or elsewhere.

Comment: I updated the question with the answer to the requested lpstat commands.  (I couldn't put that text in this comment due to too many characters)

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem. I could not see printers aside from PDF to file. Also when tried to print to file, it wasn't working, no error displayed. When Okular started from terminal, printing to file displayed error:

GPL Ghostscript 9.55.0: Can't find initialization file gs_init.ps.

I solved issue by removing program in Ubuntu software, then choosing .deb version instead of snap version in top and after installing .deb version, I can see my printer available.

So this seems to be snap version problem. Probably permissions?

Comment: created https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=475530